# How do I combine N non-numerical columns while removing null values?

Tags: python, pandas

Building on this question [Combining columns and removing NaNs Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350655/combining-columns-and-removing-nans-pandas),

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
col     x       y        z

a1      a       NaN      NaN
a2      NaN     b        NaN
a3      NaN     c        NaN
a4      NaN     NaN      d
a5      NaN     e        NaN
a6      f       NaN      NaN
a7      g       NaN      NaN
a8      NaN     NaN      NaN
```

The cell values are strings and the NaNs are arbitrary null values.

I would like to combine the columns to add a new combined column thus:

```
col  w

a1   a
a2   b
a3   c
a4   d
a5   e
a6   f
a7   g
a8   NaN
```

The elegant solution proposed in the question above uses

```
df['w']=df[['x','y','z']].sum(axis=1)
```

but sum does not work for non-numerical values.

How, in this case for strings, do I combine the columns into a single column?

You can assume:

1. Each row only has one of `x`, `y`, `z` that is non-null.
2. The individual columns must be referenced by name (since they are a subset of all of the available columns in the dataframe).
3. In general there are N and not just 3 columns in the subset.
4. Hopefully no use for iloc/for loops :\

**Update: (apologies to those who have already given answers :\ )**

5. I have added a final row where every column contains NaN, and I would like the combined row to reflect that. Thanks + sorry!

Thanks as ever for all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is yet another solution:

```
df['res'] = df.fillna('').sum(1).replace('', np.nan)
```

The result is

```
       x    y    z  res
col                    
a1     a  NaN  NaN    a
a2   NaN    b  NaN    b
a3   NaN    c  NaN    c
a4   NaN  NaN    d    d
a5   NaN    e  NaN    e
a6     f  NaN  NaN    f
a7     g  NaN  NaN    g
a8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This is amazing and also deals with the update to the question, for which thanks. I have to leave the answers open for a few hours.

Comment: Thanks, I see you reverted your answer to accommodate! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
s = df[['x','y','z']]
df['w'] = s.values[s.notnull()]
df[['col','w']]
```

Or After edit of question:

```
df['w'] = pd.DataFrame(df[['x','y','z']].apply(lambda x: x.values[x.notnull()],axis=1).tolist())
df[['col','w']].fillna(np.nan)
```

Which gives

```
    col w
0   a1  a
1   a2  b
2   a3  c
3   a4  d
4   a5  e
5   a6  f
6   a7  g
7   a8  NaN
```

Comment: So sorry - I have updated the question - are you able to reflect the update? :\

Comment: @jtlz2 This numpy vectorized approach for the problem inspired by my previous solution(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113568/generate-new-dataframe-without-nan-values/52113743#52113743).

Comment: Oh gosh - does this mean my Q is a dupe? :\

Comment: Thx so so much!

Comment: @jtlz2 Updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generic sum, you have to apply a custom function.
This one, for example works on your example:

```
import numpy as np
f = lambda x: x[x.notnull()][0] if any(x.notnull()) else np.nan
df['w'] = df[list('xyz')].apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have updated the question - is your answer adaptable? :\

Comment: Yes, I did adapt it.

Comment: Welcome! I must say anyway that I like the answer of sobek better than mine... :)